# Apple Watch Force Touch Menu

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, apple-watch

I just recently noticed it is possible to add a force touch gesture to my watch app. I've added a Menu and 3 Menu items... as seen here:

[image]

Although, when I force touch, the menu does *not* come up.

Do I need to do something else to get this thing working?

Tutorials suggest I do not. Thus, I turn to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

By default, each menu item's image is set to Custom in the attributes inspector, and without an image asset selected here a menu item won't appear at all upon a firm press. You'll have to choose one of the images that Apple provides in the attributes inspector Image dropdown menu or provide your own asset where it says No Image right below.